# How to show image in html img element more than 260 file path

Tags: html, image, path, element

I am developing some java-script app showing images in long path with windows PC.
I know that windows had a path limitation, and now I can show images with long path in windows explorer.
But it can't show with html img element.
I think that is caused by some kind of browser limitation.

Is there any way to show images in html img element with over 260 characters path.
Additionally I can't copy images with short path, because images are too huge and copy time may be occur bad customer experience.

Comment: What kind of path are you using ? UNC or drive letter related ? absolute or relative paths ? src html attribute of img tag has no limitation since you can embed base64 encoded image in it that can be very long (in megabytes). What version of windows are you talking about ? With windows API you can use extended path, beginning with \\?\ and is 32k long. With Windows 10 you can get rid of path limitation. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

Comment: Sorry for less information.
Path is UNC absolute path.
windows version is 10.
I know that I can get rid of path limitation. So I can see image with photo app. But when I set image path to img element, that can not be shown.

Comment: Possible problem could be that since you try to retrieve information with unc path, it may be a right access problem since it is the web server that try to read your images. A cross domain problem could also be involved. What kind of error do you see in the console/network tools of your browser ?

Comment: I didn't use embed base64 encoded image. Is that the cause of unshowing the image? If so, is there any way to show image without base64 encoded image? 
 Because I have too many jpg images that must be kept original data, and jpg to baes64 convert is too slow to show images sequencialy.

Comment: Now I find the difference between a image that can be shown and not. A image that can be show has long name, ant the other has short name confirmed with file property. So I think I can show image if short name can be set to img element src. Is there any way to get short name from long name?

Comment: What error message do you see in the console/network tools of your browser ?

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question.
error message is 

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND [file://xxx.xx.xx.xx/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc/dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd.jpg]"

like that. File path is not actual one.